# AlertView? Alert? What is it?

Tags: ios, user-interface, hud

I've seen some cool looking "windows" / "alerts" /whatever they are called. I wish I knew. Here's some examples of them:

[image] [image]

These shouldn't be Apple exclusive, since I've seen 3rd party apps use them! I'd like to know what are these windows?

Comment: so while you added the arrows in the image manipulation program, why didn't you scale and/or crop it a bit?

Comment: ok, I'll scale them down a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It Custom `UIActivityIndicator` that you can found in this link

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

`MBProgressHUD` is an iOS drop-in class that displays a translucent HUD with an indicator and/or labels while work is being done in a background thread. The HUD is meant as a replacement for the undocumented, private UIKit UIProgressHUD with some additional features.......
**For mor information go to above Link**

Thanks :)

Comment: The MBProgressHUD is just what I needed and it has many options, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These is not apple specific controls. You can create them.
The pop up shown in first image is very easy to make. You'll have to use 3 controls to make it.

1. Background UIImageView with the image.
2. `UIActivityIndicatory`
3. `UILabel` with whatever message you want to display.

You just have to load this `UIImageView` and Animate the `UIActivityIndicatory` to get this pop up. I've used these pop up in a lot of apps Apple don't object this.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer, however, MBProgressHUD is (accordion to me) easier to use

Answer (score 1):

Your first view is a UIProgressHUD. Original Apple HUD is in a private API and it is not recommended to use it. 
http://cocoadev.com/wiki/UIProgressHUD

However, numerous implementations have appeared that emulate the original HUD. For one, have a look here:
https://github.com/y0n3l/LGViewHUD
though I am sure Google will give you a dozen similar implementations.